# ActiveAdmin Custom page with index table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have created a custom page with `ActiveAdmin` as follows:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "message_list" do

  controller do
    def index
      @collection = client().account.messages.list.sort_by{ |message| Date.rfc2822(message.date_sent) }.reverse
      render :layout => 'active_admin'
    end
  end
end
```

I have created an index.html.erb file with a table that I want to display on this page. This however is not optimal. How do I use the active admin standard table layout that also comes with pagination and display it with my table info? I know that ActiveAdmin PageDSL Class does not include #index and therefore I can't simply do:

```
  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :to
    column :from
    default_actions
  end
```

In addition to achieving the `ActiveAdmin` table layout on a custom page, how do I change the Title of the page itself? As of now it is called "Index".

Answer (score 13):

An easier method would be to define an ActiveAdmin resource for your message class, `Message`, and limit the actions to only allow `:index`.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Message do
  actions :index

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :to
    column :from
    default_actions
  end

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      super.where(account_id: account.id).order(:date_sent)

      # Or provide a custom collection similar to the current implementation:
      # client().account.messages.list.sort_by{ |message| Date.rfc2822(message.date_sent) }.reverse
    end

  end
end
```

It is also possible to rename the resource if necessary by providing an `:as` option to the `#register` method:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Message, as: "Account Message" do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Super.!! Thanks CMaresh., This is what I was searching for. Great job.. How did you come to know this..?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking to hide the unnecessary rows by using jquery if i dont get solution in active admin. But, you saved me. Thanks :) :)

Comment: The usage is mentioned in the ActiveAdmin docs: [Customizing resource retrieval](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#customizing-resource-retrieval)

Answer (score 8):

While the accepted answer works well if you can use an ActiveAdmin resource instead of a custom page, it is possible to get an index-style table on a custom page via [Arbre](https://github.com/activeadmin/arbre):

```
<%=
  Arbre::Context.new({}, self) do
    table_for(client().account.messages, sortable: true, class: 'index_table') do
      column :id
      column :created_at
    end
  end
%>
```